# Modify boundaries using solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I would like to that if it is possible modify the election in the boundaries for solve a system of differential equations, because for solve_ivp the boundaries condition are given in t=0, but I want to change them for diferent initial time "t", for example how could I do this in the next example

dx=x+y; x(0)=1

dy=x-y; y(1)=1

Any advice is welcome, thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you set up your system. Show the code you used to solve it for constant boundary conditions and it can probably be modified to suit your case.

Comment: This is a boundary value problem, a BVP, and thus needs to be solved with `solve_bvp`. Alternatively you can implement a single-shooting method with `solve_ivp` and `fsolve`.